# what are the difference between features of windows mobile(past Os) and windows phone 7 Os?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, windows-phone-7.1

AnyOne please help me out i need to know the what are the features supported in windows mobile and what are supported in windows phone 7 and not supported compare to windows mobile. 
For ex.getting current running processes list it will support in windows mobile but we are not able to find in windows phone 7 .
please let me know the reference links......

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Many functionality of Windows Mobile are not available in windows Phone,  "Radio Interface Library" for sample, Windows phone is much more closed than Windows MObile, but it's different, Windows Phone provides additional functionality...
Also, many other functionality appears with the next OS Windows Phone 8...

Answer (score 1):

The API references are found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123401

In general: if you don't find it, then it doesn't exist.

There's no such thing as a one-by-one comparison/translation table.